# AST Transformation is not being applied to dependent plugin domain classes when calling grails run-app

Tags: grails, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have several plugins which have AST Transformations and one plugin (called Core) that contains domain classes which needs these AST Transformations available at compile time.  The transformations seem to be applied if I run maven-install on the Core plugin, but when I try to run grails run-app on my application which uses these plugins, the AST Transformation doesn't seem to be applied to any of my domain classes in my Core plugin.

What is the best approach to compile all my AST Transformation classes and have it available to the compiler in time for when my domain classes (which are in another plugin) are compiled?

Using Grails 2.3.8

Comment: I suppose that is similar to the next question http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/creating-custom-annotations-for-domain-classes-td4487250.html

Comment: I have the same problem here, have you solve your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27738864/2711378 here is my answer on the topic!

Answer (score 0):

Try anotating your target class with the full reference.

Instead of

```
import ASTpackage.*
@ASTInterface
class Foo {
...
```

Use

```
import ASTpackage.*
@ASTpackage.ASTInterface
class Foo {
...
```

Don't know why but worked